# POST request RouteXL with Excel VBA gives blank response

Tags: json, excel, vba, http-post

Im trying to write a POST request to get an optimized route via RouteXL API. For testing i have used their location coordinates inside my request body: https://www.routexl.com/blog/api/#get-status

However, my response is 409: No input found. So it seems like something is wrong with the parameters i have added. I have tried to figure it out, but i need some help from you guys. What am i doing wrong here?

```
Function ReqPOSTxl(url As String, key As String)

Dim Req As New XMLHTTP60

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Req.Open "POST", url, False

Req.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"

Req.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
Req.setRequestHeader "Accept-Crs", "epsg:4258"
Req.setRequestHeader "X-Api-Key", key
Req.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncodeBase64("username:password")

Dim API_body As String
API_body = "locations=[{""address"":""The Hague, The Netherlands"",""lat"":""52.05429"",""lng"":""4.248618""},{""address"":""The Hague, The Netherlands"",""lat"":""52.076892"",""lng"":""4.26975""},{""address"":""Uden, The Netherlands"",""lat"":""51.669946"",""lng"":""5.61852""},{""address"":""Sint-Oedenrode, The Netherlands"",""lat"":""51.589548"",""lng"":""5.432482""}]"
Debug.Print API_body

Req.send (API_body)

Debug.Print Req.responseText
Set ReqPOSTxl = ParseJson(Req.responseText)
```

End Function

Comment: If the request body is meant to be JSON, in this case a JSON array, then drop the leading `locations=` from your API_body string as in its current way it is not JSON.

Comment: That's what i tried at first, but that wont work as well..

Comment: So which URI did you POST to? The status is for a GET request.

Comment: The response is JSON but the request `Content-Type` should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See Javascript example [here](https://github.com/routexl/RouteXL-API-Connector/blob/master/Javascript/routexl-api.js)

Comment: Tnx guys! i have found the error. As mentioned above, the Content-Type was wrong and i had to change the API_BODY to "location=" + json array